# Too many re-renders (React, useState)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The idea is that when the user presses the right letter on the keyboard (the first letter of the bird's name), the first bird's name from the birds array will be deleted, so the user can continue to guess until the array is empty. I get an error: *Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.* I tried to fix the problem with useEffect but it didn't work (maybe I did not used it correctly).

**Here is the code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// Usage
function App() {

  const [birds, setBirds] = useState(['rambo', 'rio', 'charlie', 'coco', 'cleo', 'sunny', 'daffy', 'aldo', 'daisy', 'baxter'])
  const [currentBird, setCurrentBird] = useState(birds[0])
  const [birdArray, setBirdArray] = useState(currentBird.split(""))
  // Call our hook for each key that we'd like to monitor
  const birdFirstLetter = useKeyPress(birdArray[0]); // return true or false



  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {birdFirstLetter && setBirds(birds.slice(1))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Hook
function useKeyPress(targetKey) {
  // State for keeping track of whether key is pressed
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);

  // If pressed key is our target key then set to true
  function downHandler({ key }) {
    if (key === targetKey) {
      setKeyPressed(true);
    }
  }

  // If released key is our target key then set to false
  const upHandler = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === targetKey) {
      setKeyPressed(false);
    }
  };

  // Add event listeners
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
    // Remove event listeners on cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
    };
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount and unmount

  return keyPressed;
}

export default App;
```

**That way is also not working(same outcome):**

```
function App() {

  const [birds, setBirds] = useState(['rambo', 'rio', 'charlie', 'coco', 'cleo', 'sunny', 'daffy', 'aldo', 'daisy', 'baxter'])
  const [currentBird, setCurrentBird] = useState(birds[0])
  const [birdArray, setBirdArray] = useState(currentBird.split(""))
  // Call our hook for each key that we'd like to monitor
  const birdFirstLetter = useKeyPress(birdArray[0]); // return true or false

  if (birdFirstLetter){
    setBirds(birds.slice(1))
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {/*birdFirstLetter && setBirds(birds.slice(1))*/}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

...
...
...

export default App
```

Comment: what are you exactly trying to achieve? you are getting too many re-renders because you are using `setState` inside `render` which isn't a good idea as it will set the state then render, over and over

Comment: Basically I am trying to remove the first element from the array(birds) when the user press the right key.

Comment: have added an answer

Answer (score 0):

One of the principles of react:
never change state in jsx or render it will overflow the stack limit.
doing state change in render or jsx will cause component to re-render, that's why you are getting too many re-renders.

remove 'setBirds' from JSX, it will not throw error.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this?

```
const removeElement = () => {
   setBirds(birds.slice(1))
}

<div onKeyPress={removeElement}>
   {/*birdFirstLetter && setBirds(birds.slice(1))*/}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes the idea is the same, but I tried like that and it doesn't work:

```const removeElement = () =>{
  if (birdFirstLetter){
    setBirds(birds.slice(1))
    console.log('first element deleted')
    return
  }
  console.log('not the right key')
}```

Comment: can you explain really clearly what you want? when I press a key, what should happen? and is it any key or a particular key?

Comment: The key is particular key. The key is the first letter of the bird's name.
For example: *This is the array with the birds names* `const [birds, setBirds] = useState(['rambo', 'rio', 'charlie', 'coco', 'cleo', 'sunny', 'daffy', 'aldo', 'daisy', 'baxter'])`

For the first element of the array (rambo) the key must be "r"
For the second element of the array (rio) the key must be "r"
For the third element of the array (charlie) the key must be "c"  ......
*If statement will check is it the right key and if it is will delete the first element of the array*

Comment: so if I type in `c` as the first key, what happens? as `rambo` is the first element, nothing?

Comment: Yes it should not have anything or latter I can of course add some text informing the user that this is not the right key.

Comment: sorry I'm just really confused by what you want. what is the user trying to do? find the right word?

Comment: https://prismic-io.s3.amazonaws.com/devaja/950646df-ff9b-42a9-824b-0d08d7499af7_devaja_exercises.pdf

*This is a link for the exercise(Exercise 1)*

Comment: Hi, @Red ! I figured out a solution, here is link to the repository:
https://github.com/VasIvan/devaja1